# Symfony 1.4: How I can retrieve the selected value with AJAX's function in select dependent?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony-1.4

In my database I have two related fields. The second field depends on the value selected in the first. The relations are:

[image]

The function I use in the form of table "conflictos_1" is:

```
<!--Aquí el javascript para select dependientes-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#conflictos1_id_sector_actividad").change(function()
    {
        var id_sub = $(this).val();
        if(id_sub != '')
        {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo url_for('conflictos/subsector'); ?>'+ '?id=' + id_sub,
                cache: false,
                data: "id_sub="+ id_sub,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#conflictos1_id_subsector_actividad").html(data); // but it does not select the value of dropdown list.
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#conflictos1_id_subsector_actividad").html("<option value=''>-- No se ha seleccionado subsector --</option>");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When I add a new record, everything works fine. 
But when I edit a record, the select dependent, does not show "selected" value.
In edit mode, when I look at the field "id_subsector_actividad", the selected value should be, for example, `<option value="37 "   selected="selected">`: This is what I see on my form  when I inspect the element created with AJAX's function:

```
<select name="conflictos1[id_subsector_actividad]" id="conflictos1_id_subsector_actividad">
   <option value="29 ">14.1 Meretrices</option>        
   <option value="30 ">Preparación de alimentos y comedor</option>        
   <option value="31 ">Seguridad</option>        
   <option value="37 ">redes sanitarias</option>        
</select>
```

This is what I WANT to see:

```
<select name="conflictos1[id_subsector_actividad]" id="conflictos1_id_subsector_actividad">
       <option value="29 ">14.1 Meretrices</option>        
       <option value="30 ">Preparación de alimentos y comedor</option>        
       <option value="31 ">Seguridad</option>        
       <option value="37 "  selected="selected">redes sanitarias</option>        
    </select>
```

I use this function to filter records in the table "Subsector_actividad_ta8"(I work with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine):

```
    public function executeSubsector() 
    { $id_sub = $_POST['id_sub']; 
$this->subsec= Doctrine_Core::getTable('SubsectorActividadTa8') ->createQuery('a') 
    ->where('a.id_sector = ?', $id_sub) 
    ->execute(); 
    }
```

My question is: What should I change in the AJAX's function, to display the "selected" value in the second field, when I am editing an existing record?

Comment: you need to show your server side code

Comment: It looks like the data being returned by your server doesn't contain any selected item.

Comment: @Matanya I use this function to filter records (I work with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine): `public function executeSubsector()

    {
        $id_sub = $_POST['id_sub'];
   
       $this->subsec= Doctrine_Core::getTable('SubsectorActividadTa8')
                ->createQuery('a')
                ->where('a.id_sector = ?', $id_sub) 
                ->execute();   
    } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution I encountered: I've separated the problem in two.

**Case 1: New Record**

I use the same JQuery function shown above in the question. With the associated function, also shown above. This case was not part of my problem

**Case 2: Edit an existing record (here was my problem)**

I added for `'id_subsector_actividad'`    in the widget the property  `'table_method'=>'Subsector'` associated with the  function `public function Subsector()` (see below code).

In the partial  _form.php of conflictos1,  I wrote the following code for the field `id_subsector_actividad`:

```
<?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>       
         <?php echo $form['id_subsector_actividad'] ?>    
    <?php endif; ?>                 
 <?php if ($form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>   
             <select name="conflictos1[id_subsector_actividad]" id="conflictos1_id_subsector_actividad">

              <option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione sub-sector</option>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

In the action.class.php in the conflictos1, I modified the function executeEdit, with the addition of the variable `$elsector`:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
 global $elsector;
    $this->forward404Unless($conflictos1 = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Conflictos1')->find(array($request->getParameter('id'))), sprintf('Object conflictos1 does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));

    $elsector= $conflictos1->getIdSectorActividad(); 


    $this->form = new Conflictos1Form($conflictos1);


  }
```

I use `$elsector` in the following function created in `SubsectorActividadTa8Table.class.php`

```
public function Subsector()

    {
         global $elsector;


         if (!is_null($elsector)){
       $id_sub=$elsector;
       $query= Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('a.id')
            ->from('SubsectorActividadTa8 a')
         ->innerJoin('a.Conflictos1 c')

           ->where('a.id_sector = ?', $id_sub); 
               return $query->execute();  
    }
    }
```

Thus, Symfony displayed on the form, the value of field named IdSubsectorActividad, not previously exhibited.

In other words, now when I'm editing a record in the table `conflictos1` the field named IdSubsectorActividad  shows the correct value, whereas before the form does not show any value.

Now everything works fine!.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with something like:

```
$("option[value='37']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

You have a similar question on: [Set selected option of select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)

Comment: Your ansewr not work, because the second select is created by the AJAX's function. In my form, I only have this line: `<select name="conflictos1[id_subsector_actividad]" id="conflictos1_id_subsector_actividad">
           
              <option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione sub-sector</option>`